# EF Core Backing fields - expose property as another type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Assume I have an EF entity class Person, with a PhoneNumber on it. PhoneNumber is stored as a string type, but I want all accesses on the Person to go through Phone  which has some nice accessor functions, e.g. validation or `GetAreaCode()`. I want to back it in the db as a string, but when queried for it I want to return it as a PhoneNumber:

```
public class Person {
    public PhoneNumber Phone { /* Some clever get/set logic here */ }

    private string _phoneNumber; // Backing field
}
```

Or can I get PhoneNumber to store itself as a string? If I simply include it in the model by removing the backing field above, EF gets confused by the constructors (a protected ctor with some more args than the one string) and also a copy ctor `PhoneNumber(PhoneNumber other)`. Can i make EF ignore those  somehow?

I'm open to ideas...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I've found that works in EF Core 2.0 is to create a public property with getters/setters **with a name that does not match your backing field** and mark it as NotMapped, like so:

```
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Fire Type")]
    public Enums.FireType Type
    {
        get
        {
            Enums.FireType type;
            if (!Enum.TryParse(_fireType, out type))
                type = Enums.FireType.Fire; // default

            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            _fireType = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    
    private string _fireType;
```

Then in your DbContext's OnModelCreating method, tell it to create a column on the database table that acts like a backing property:

```
        // backing properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fire>()
            .Property<string>("FireType")
            .HasField("_fireType")
            .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

With that, I was finally able to create a successful migration that allowed me to have a private field on my model, a public transformative property on the model, and a single properly-named column in my database table. The only catch is that the public property and the private field can't share the same name (without sharing the same type), but that wasn't going to be the case for you, anyway.

Comment: Very nice! A pity one have to do this kind of trickery, but it did solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Even copy pasting your example does not work and results in an exception: `The specified field '_fireType' cannot be used for the property 'Foo.FireType' because it does not match the property name.`. EF Core 3.1.

Comment: Agree with Krzaku - at least in 3.1 this does not work, thus the down-vote

Comment: ```public long _deliveryTime;[NotMapped]public TimeSpan DeliveryTime {get => TimeSpan.FromTicks(_deliveryTime); set => _deliveryTime = value.Ticks; }``` with ```.Property<long>(nameof(Product.DeliveryTime)).HasField(nameof(Product._deliveryTime)).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);``` gives following error: "The property 'DeliveryTime' cannot be added to type 'Product' because the type of the corresponding CLR property or field 'TimeSpan' does not match the specified type 'long'." on add migration

Comment: @deadManN This was a working suggestion when the question was asked (back in 2018, for EF Core 2.0), but this is no longer the recommended solution.

Unfortunately, people will keep coming to this old topic and trying old answers. I don't know of any way to clearly mark this as anachronistic.

Comment: if it was json i would use something like this `private [JsonProperty('Data')] long DataTimeLong` and then `public [JsonIgnore] TimeSpan Data {get {DataTimeLong} set{DataTimeLong}}` the code i wrote here is not valid but is short, to show my intention. but it is not possible in EF... even something was in documentation, that didn't worked for me too, although it wasn't exactly what i wanted, and forced you to name your property in their desired way, not yours... Also most cases cause EF to create new column in DB. Do you know any link to solution? although I handle it manually in service.

Answer (score 14):

You can use @nbrosz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565007/797882) to fix your issue but you no longer need to do this kind of workaround if you're using EF Core 2.1. You can rid of the backing field by using EF Core 2.1 (which is in [Release Candidate 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1-rc-1/) since 7 May 2018) you can use the feature of Value Conversion explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) by Microsoft:

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
>   from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value
>   to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from
>   a value of one type to a value of another type (for example,
>   converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

So for your case, you can just remove the backing field. You no longer need it. Your class should look like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    public PhoneNumber Phone { /* Some clever get/set logic here */ }
}
```

And in your `OnModelCreating` method, you configure the conversion like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Phone)
    .HasConversion(
        phone => { 
            // Here you code the logic of how to get the value to store in DB
            return ...;
        },
        dbValue => { 
            // Here you code the logic of how to construct the PhoneNumber instance from the value to store in DB
        }
    );
```

That's it. Actually it is in release candidate but Microsoft says:

> EF Core 2.1 RC1 is a “go live” release, which means once you test that
>   your application works correctly with RC1, you can use it in
>   production and obtain support from Microsoft, but you should still
>   update to the final stable release once it’s available.

This remainder of my answer is for **@nbrosz** because you are dealing with enum type. You can remove the backing field and also you can one of the many built-in value converters provided by EF Core 2.1. For enum to string value conversion we have the type `EnumToStringConverter`. For the logic you're doing in your answer, you can just simplify it to this for entity:

```
[Display(Name = "Fire Type")]
public Enums.FireType Type { get; set; }
```

We removed the `NotMapped` attribute on the property and there is no logic y for conversion.

In your `OnModelCreating` method you do this:

```
var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<FireType>();

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Fire>()
    .Property(e => e.FireType)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

You can also let EF Core detects the right converter for you  by using the generic version of `HasConversion<T>` like below:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Fire>()
    .Property(e => e.FireType)
    .HasConversion<string>();
```

If you don't like to use fluent configuration you can use `Column` data annotation attibute like below and EF Core will do the conversion for you:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(20)")]
[Display(Name = "Fire Type")]
public Enums.FireType Type { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm very much liking the look of this, and it certainly solves what has been a large pain in the butt for me. Too bad our server admins are unlikely to go Core 2.1 any time soon. I can't even get them to go above 2.0.3.

Comment: @nbrosz you should look for self container application in .Net Core. This allows you to deploy your applications with the runtime so your application will not need the server to install specific runtime.

Comment: I think it is important to mention that custom value converters tend to result in client-side query evaluation.

Comment: @MattJenkins you can fix that by using `ValueConverterSelector`.Check [this article](https://andrewlock.net/strongly-typed-ids-in-ef-core-using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-4/) for more details.

Comment: ```public TimeSpan DeliveryTime { get; set; }``` and ```builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.DeliveryTime).HasConversion(p => p.Ticks, p2 => TimeSpan.FromTicks(p2));``` gives "Operand type clash: time is incompatible with bigint" error :| on update migration

Comment: ValueConverters don't work in every situation, specifically when you're dealing with nullables. You'll have to use the backing field technique. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13850