# Is there a way to apply value conversion on backing fields?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

**Question:** Is there a way in Entity Framework Core 3.0 to apply [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) on [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field)?

**Context:**
Let's say I have a Blog entity that contains a list of string values representing post ids. I want to avoid the need to have a join entity/table (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53703521/638167)) so I do a conversion to store the list as a string in the DB. I also want to protect my model from being modified directly through the PostIds property, so I want to use a backing field for that (as described [here](https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core)).

Something like this:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    private readonly List<string> _postIds;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> PostIds => _postIds;

    public Blog()
    {
        _posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}
```

And configuration of the context would look something like that:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{
    // Configuring the backing field
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .Metadata
                .FindNavigation(nameof(Blog.PostIds))
                .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

    // Trying to configure the value conversion, but that doesn't work...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .Property(e => e.PostIds)
                .HasConversion(v => string.Join(',', v),
                               v => v.Split(','));
}
```

Any ideas how this configuration could be achieved with the current version of Entity Framework (3.0)?

Comment: You can simply make the backing field `string` and the navigation property computed from the backing field.

Comment: And if you want to modify the list within the entity class, you can make: (1) a `string` type backing field, (2) a private `IList<string>` property which is implemented by yourself to read from and write to the backing field ,which must have a different name and should be set ignored by EF Core (3) a public navigation property with the same (but CamelCase) name to be configured as `PropertyAccessMode.Field` which converts (2) to a `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` for external read access.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Owned Entity Types to have it stored in a different data table but mapped as an Entity or Value Object to be accessed only via the `Blog` aggregate root.

Comment: Did you ever find out a real solution? I believe the comments above only post workarounds that do not make use of value conversion from ef core

Comment: @S.tenBrinke ten Brinke I don't remember if we found a way to fix it. Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375161/638167